# Have you gone to the movies lately?

Tags: grammar

I've known about the difference between *Have gone to* vs. *Have been to* for quite a while:

> She has been to the movies.
>   (She has probably left the theater and is possibly back home.)
>
> She has gone to the movies.
>   (She has probably not returned yet.)

Nevertheless, one of my friends wrote the following question: 
Have you gone to the movies lately?

I know the usual question would be: 
Have you been to the movies lately?

However, due to the use of the adverb "lately", wouldn't it be acceptable to use *Have gone* as well?

I've searched the other threads but I haven't found a question about this subject involving the adverbs lately or recently.

Comment: "Have you gone to the movies lately?" is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: Further, I would say that *have you gone* is even more common than *have you been* in this context. There is no problem here, and no need to rephrase the quite natural original sentence.

Comment: Thank you! If anyone else would like to chime in, I'd appreciate it.